# How to push data from local server to Android Device - No GCM, No Internet Connection

Tags: android, push-notification, push

Is there a way to push data from local server (hosted on intranet) to an Android application without internet connection? The app is supposed to work only on LAN over wifi. GCM is out of picture as internet connection is not available. However the app will be running on both the devices all the time.

The model, I am talking about, is something like this:

Devices: Local Server - Wifi Connection - Android Device 1, Android Device 2

Android Device 1 updates some data on local server over wifi... Server needs to notify Android Device 2 about the change over Wifi.

Thank You very much for the help

Comment: Have you looked a websockets you can run that locally over wifi just give the devices the address of the server and it should work fine. Take a look at socketIO.

Comment: I've used Sockets for an app at home. I followed this tutorial, really easy to follow, and port over into Android. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I used sockets connection to do so.

```
requestSocket = new Socket();
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, portNumber);                 
requestSocket.connect(socketAddress, timeOutPeriod);
```

At the server end, you need to open those sockets and ports using whatever languages you prefer. After which you can read or write data using streams.

Comment: I have tried same like above. Getting error like below System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at something like [socketIO](http://socket.io/)  for that used in a project not that long ago and as long as you know the server address and it is the same on both devices you should be able to push data to and from the server from any device. A group of us used it to make a note taking app. you may need to build your app in html and javascript unless you want to use the java socket communication that would also do the job but more work would be involved.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I need further information.

What is the difference between WebSockets and the normal sockets? 

For my Use case, local server is running in Windows with MySQL data base connectivity. So if I wanna use SocketIO, So I have to write the Server code based on SocketIo in for Windows local server and the Client code in Android App. ? 

If I use the SocketIO, does it have the PUSH to Android app feature?

Comment: To ue socketIO you would need to build a server side server system for socketIO this is usually done in node.js but can be done with other languages such as python. Not sure about a push to android app feature  usually program as a html5 app and package it with something like triggerIO an make it poll for changes at a set interval.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can implement Message Queue using message server